# How to define a date interval in a compatible way?

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, hsqldb

I am trying to construct the SQL query, that should be executed *as is*
 both on HSQL (v2.2.4) and MySQL (v5.1.36) server (if it can run also on DB2 v9, that would be wonderful bonus!)

The query is:

```
select count(*) from document where current_date - cast(indexing_date as date) <= ?
```

(here `current_date` is a standard HSQL/MySQL function and `indexing_date` is a column with type `datetime`, parameter `?` is substituted by integer `20` which is the number of days).

The problem is that MySQL returns the difference between dates [as between numbers](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,433055,433080) while HSQL returns the difference in days (which is logical when you subtract date from date).

Also HSQL supports this syntax (but MySQL does not):

```
select count(*) from document where cast(indexing_date as date) between current_date - 20 day and current_date
```

while MySQL does not. I am aware about [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) in MySQL, but as I said the solution should be inter-operable.

Comment: MySQL supports also: `current_date - INTERVAL 20 day`

Comment: I don't think is possible, hsqldb syntax is so different from mysql.

Comment: @ypercube: Does not work for HSQLDB: `Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: INTERVAL`.

Comment: @ajreal: Perhaps HSQL is more compatible with SQL'92? MySQL supports many nice extensions, but they are non-standard.

Comment: True.I have no experience on hsqldb, but I just take a glance on the datediff function, is very different from MySQL datediff. Highly unlikely you are able to construct universal SQL for both database. I think it will save more trouble if you are able to split into two SQL format for each database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB also supports this:

```
select count(*) from document where current_date - cast(indexing_date as date) <= cast(? as interval day)
```

and

```
select count(*) from document where cast(indexing_date as date) between current_date - '20' day and current_date
```

or

```
select count(*) from document where indexing_date >= current_date - interval '20' day
```

Also, from version 2.2.6, HSQLDB supports `DATEDIFF(datevaluea, datevalueb)`, which returns the number of days between the two dates, as well as `DAYS(datevalue)`, which returns the day number since the epoch.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments here and also replies on [HSQL forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674/topic/4382354/). Definitely +1, but MySQL refuses the syntax `cast(? as interval day)`. It looks like I really need to check the DB in the code...

Comment: On [MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,433057,433570,quote=1#REPLY) the conclusion was that there is only way to write this query.

Comment: OK. We might add support for INTERVAL ? DAY although this is not ANSI SQL. Same with DATEDIFF(date, date), DATE and DAYS functions

Comment: Could you provide a link to SQL spec, which you use as a basis for syntax grammar? I would love to open a bug for MySQL, but I need a reference (e.g. what is "correct" syntax). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have doublechecked the 3rd query: I've got the exception `unexpected token: '20' near line 1, column NNN` for HSQLDB 2.2.4. Hopefully 2.2.6 is pushed to Maven soon.

Comment: Thanks for spec link. Actually, I looked it once, but perhaps not very attentive. For one who is interested, that is page 239 "10.1  <interval qualifier>".

Answer (score 0):

db2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM document 
WHERE DATE(indexing_date) BETWEEN DATE(DAYS(CURRENT DATE) - 20) AND CURRENT DATE
```

Comment: Thank you for comments, but is your query compatible either with MySQL or HSQL? If not, can you please suggest the one that is compatible?

Comment: sorry i do not know the other two DBMs, this is just a suggestion to try it on your DBM